# Python decode and encode

Tags: python, unicode

I cannot figure out how to feed the list of decimal codepoints for them to be decoded (or encoded?) via a specific codepage.

```
str_0 = 'abc'
lst_decimal = list(str_0.encode("utf-8"))
for i in lst_decimal:
    print (str(int(i)).decode("cp437"))
```

Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_0.encode("utf-8")` returns a `bytes` object, which has a `decode` method, but when you turn it into a list, it becomes a list on ints. Just keep it as a bytes object:

```
my_bytes = str_0.encode("utf-8") 
print (my_bytes.decode("cp437")) #prints abc
```

Even more simply:

```
print(str_0.encode("utf-8").decode("cp437"))
```

As an added benefit, there is no need for using `decode` in a loop -- the entire `bytes` object can be decoded at once.

If you wanted to keep your original `lst_decimal` and do what you were trying to do, your loop could look like:

```
for i in lst_decimal:
    print(bytes([i]).decode("cp437"))
```

`list()` turns a `bytes` object into a list of ints, and `bytes` goes backwards. Note, however that simply `bytes(i)` returns a list of `i` bytes, each initialized to `0`.

Comment: I stumbled upon print (struct.pack('B', int(i).decode('cp866'))), this did what I wanted. But is there a way to it with the method you suggested? 'i' the original decimal value I want to have a possibility to change.

Comment: @DmitryStarostin What I gave at the end should work. In your comment here, i is already an integer so `int(i)` is superfluous. `bytes([i]).decode()` works -- but note the square brackets! There is an `int.to_bytes()` method, but it isn't very convenient (you need specify number of bytes and byte order). One complicating fact is that when you convert `bytes` to a list of ints, those ints are in range 0-255. With Unicode, an individual character might correspond to 2 or even more bytes. `ord()` gives you the actual codepoint of a Unicode character.